# Как работает append

Tags: golang

обьясните пожалуйста, как append работает с памятью.

если есть один срез, у которго каждый элемент ссылается на определенный адрес в памяти, то  я могу изменить значение по этому адресу другой функцией и мне не нужно для этого чтобы эта другая функция вызвращала что либо, мне достаточно, чтобы она работала со значением по тому же адресу в который вызывающая функция положила значние. Почему же, если я пытаюсь в другой функции одно значение изменить явно по индексу, а остальные заполнить с помощью append то то что я изменил по индексу будет изменено, а то что я попытался изменить с помощью append нет.

```
func someAction(v []int8, b int8) {
    println(&v[0])
    v[0] = 100
    //нулевой индекс изменится а остальное нет
    v = append(v, b)
  }
  
  func main() {
    var a = []int8{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    println(&a[0]) //тот же самй адрес в памяти что и v[0] в someAction.
    someAction(a, 6) 
    fmt.Println(a)
  }
```

С какими адресами памяти работает append?  Он создает копию среза в другом адресе?

Comment: Потому что v[0] это ссылка, а v - значение :) Если вы хотите менять весь массив а не только содержимое то передавайте по ссылке: ```func someAction(v* []int8, b int8) { v = apend....}```(так передается ссылка на массив v), а так передается копия массива v: ```func someAction(v []int8, b int8)```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков то есть append работает со значанием а и никак не затрагивает данные в адресах? получается что копия среза над которым работает append находится в другом адресе?

Comment: v передающийся в функцию является копией оригинального v, из функции он не возвращается :) если вы хотите менять адрес V - нужно передавать его по ссылке :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков мне не нужно ничего исправлять) только разобраться почему так происходит) а что, получается используется 2 слайса? для append создаётся копия v а сам v не затрагивается при этом? получается во время выполнения someFunction есть v в котором лежат значения, и копия v которая нужна для append и которая создаётся сама при вызове append?

Comment: Почитайте тогда про передачу по ссылке и по значению, разница в этом. В вашем варианте записи вы передаете копию ссылки на массив. Итого 2 разных переменных ведут к одному массиву, локальная внутри функции и та что вы передали в функцию - две разные переменные ведущие к одному массиву. Т.е. ```*a==*v; a!=v;```